# Regex for matching installation path

Tags: bash, awk

I have a requirement of extracting valid installation paths of TWS on a host from a file:

```
/usr/Tivoli/TWS/TWS/
/usr/Tivoli_123/TWS_123/TWS/
/usr/Tivoli_123/TWS/TWS_123/
/usr/Tivoli_123/XYZ/TWS
```

Any format like `/usr/Tivoli_*/TWS/TWS_*` is valid. I'm using this regex in following command:

```
cat ../TWS/test | awk -F " " '/Tivoli.*\/TWS\/TWS.*/{print $1}'
```

But it gives the output with all entries:

```
/usr/Tivoli/TWS/TWS/
/usr/Tivoli_123/TWS_123/TWS/
/usr/Tivoli_123/TWS/TWS_123/
/usr/Tivoli_123/XYZ/TWS
```

What is wrong with the regex?

Comment: `.*` matches any text including `/`. Replace `.` with `[^\/]`.

Comment: (OT: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)

Comment: `Tivoli_*` is not `Tivoli.*` but `Tivoli_.*`. Same for `TWS_` is not `TWS.*` but `TWS_.*`

Comment: @HyperioN : `TWS.*`  matches any line which contains _TWS_ somewhere. The `.*` part is redundant; you could equally well omit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any format like /usr/Tivoli_*/TWS/TWS_* is valid

Just

```
awk '/\/usr\/Tivoli_[^\/]*\/TWS\/TWS_[^\/]*/' ../TWS/test
```

should be enough to print only these lines that match.

But you can also match literally with `case` in shell:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    case "$line" in
    /usr/Tivoli_*/TWS/TWS_*) echo "$line"; ;;
    esac
done < ../TWS/test
```